# Python PyQt5 как очистить данные при закрытии окна

Tags: python, python-3.5, pyqt5

Python PyQt5.
Программа состоит из главного окна, из которого создаются/открываются новые окна и там происходит действие (например загрузка данных) или вывод результата (показать данные из базы). Проблема следующая: если вызвать окно показать результат, мы его смотрим данные, потом его закрываем, идем и грузим новые данные в программу, потом снова открываем окно показать результат, а там старые данные. Как при закрытии окна очищать данные в нем, чтоб при повторном открытии окна в нем все заново рассчитывалось
Код части программы:

```
class Ui_Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Main):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.secondWin_file = None
        self.secondWin_folder = None
        self.secondWin_makexls = None
        self.secondWin_makeshowdata = None
        self.Load_XML_file.clicked.connect(self.load_single_file)
        self.Load_XML_dir.clicked.connect(self.load_folder)
        self.make_report_2.clicked.connect(self.make_xls)
        self.show_data.clicked.connect(self.make_show_data)
        self.Quit_action.triggered.connect(self.click_exit)

    def load_single_file(self):
        if not self.secondWin_file:
            self.secondWin_file = Ui_SelectFile(self)
        self.secondWin_file.show()

    def load_folder(self):
        if not self.secondWin_folder:
            self.secondWin_folder = Ui_SelectFolder(self)
        self.secondWin_folder.show()

    def make_xls(self):
        if not self.secondWin_makexls:
            self.secondWin_makexls = Ui_MakeReport(self)
        self.secondWin_makexls.show()

    def make_show_data(self):
        if not self.secondWin_makeshowdata:
            self.secondWin_makeshowdata = Ui_ShowData(self)
        self.secondWin_makeshowdata.show()

    def click_exit(self):
        print("Выход")
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

class Ui_ShowData(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ShowData):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setupUi(self)
        out_text = ''
        start, end, dogovor = getAllPeriod(session)
        row = len(dogovor)
        self.show_data.setColumnCount(4)
        self.show_data.setRowCount(row)
        self.show_data.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Договор", "ФИО", "Начало периода", "конец периода"])
        for i in range(len(dogovor)):
            self.show_data.setItem(i,0, QTableWidgetItem(dogovor[i]))
            self.show_data.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(read_config_name(dogovor[i])))
            self.show_data.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(start[i])))
            self.show_data.setItem(i, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(end[i])))
        self.show_data.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close()
        self.destroy()
        # print("close")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        engine = create_engine("mssql://@test")
    except:
        print("ошибка подключения к БД")
        quit()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window1=Ui_Main()
    window1.show()
    app.exec_()
```

при повторном открытии окна `Ui_ShowData` данные остаются старые, а должны приехать из:

```
start, end, dogovor = getAllPeriod(session)
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем у меня ошибка?

уточнение по поводу вызова getAllPeriod:

```
def getAllPeriod(session,filter = ''):
    dogovornumber = []
    start = []
    end = []
    query = session.query(distinct(CommonData.ContractNum)).filter(CommonData.ContractNum.contains(filter)).all()
    for i in query:
        # print(i)
        a, b = getperiod(session, i[0])
        for j in range(len(a)):
            # print(i[0], a[j][0], b[j][0])
            dogovornumber.append(i[0])
            start.append(a[j][0])
            end.append(b[j][0])
    return start, end, dogovornumber
```

и не маловажное уточнение, у меня формы созданы в QtCreator-e и сконвертированы в Python, потом я их подключаю

```
from Main import Ui_Main
from ShowData import Ui_ShowData
```

и только переопределяю действия

содержимое Ui_ShowData:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_ShowData(object):
    def setupUi(self, ShowData):
        ShowData.setObjectName("ShowData")
        ShowData.resize(609, 422)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ShowData)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.show_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 601, 381))
        self.show_data.setObjectName("show_data")
        self.show_data.setColumnCount(0)
        self.show_data.setRowCount(0)
        ShowData.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(ShowData)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 609, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        ShowData.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(ShowData)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        ShowData.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(ShowData)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ShowData)

    def retranslateUi(self, ShowData):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ShowData.setWindowTitle(_translate("ShowData", "Данные в базе"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ShowData = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_ShowData()
    ui.setupUi(ShowData)
    ShowData.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Как минимум, `.show()` метод не вызывает `.__init__()` метод  (который самое большее один раз вызывается), где getAllPeriod() у вас вызывается. Обычно, в таких вещах вы новые данные модели задаёте, а GUI само обновляется.

Comment: @ jfs добавил getAllPeriod()

Comment: Переопределите метод closeEvent (или hide) и в них очищайте нужные виджеты

Comment: Я не просил определение этой функции. Я просто сказал, что она у вас из `__init__` метода вызывается.

Comment: @gil9red  в этом и вопрос. У меня прописано для класса Ui_ShowData
def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.close()
        self.destroy()
 print("close")

и как я понимаю, closeEvent должен отрабатывать при закрытии окна, причем print("close") отрабатывает, но при повторном вызове виджета отображаются старые данные, а тело виджета не отрабатывает повторно.

Comment: Извините @ jfs, но я туплю. “она у вас из __init__ метода вызывается” – можно подробнее

Comment: Ну смотрите, как бы я сделал. Данные в Ui_ShowData у вас заполняются в конструкторе, а он вызывается только один раз, поэтому вы и видите старые данные. В Ui_ShowData напишите отдельный метод, которые заполняет виджеты данными и вызываете этот метод не в конструкторе, а там где Ui_ShowData показывается через `show`, тогда переопределенную функцию closeEvent с ее странным кодом можно удалить

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял свою ошибку